# Issue while using WinForm user Control in asp.net MVC applicaton

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, user-controls, .net-framework-version

I need to use a WinForm User Control in an ASP.Net MVC4 application.

The control has been embedded using the object tag and classid attribute, but upon viewing the view in browser, only a blank frame is visible, without any cross-sign on top-left corner of frame. The viewing browser is on a machine with .Net Framework 4.5. Similar issue was faced in an ASP.Net application but same was rectified using Registry setting (EnableIEHosting = 1).

Kindly suggest.

Thanks.

Gitika

Answer (score 1):

WinForms user controls are not intended to be used from an ASP.NET (MVC or not) application.

As you should already knows, ASP.NET generate HTML codes that will be sent to the browser when requested. The browser can run on a multitude of operating systems (OS). WinForms user controls essentially only run Under Microsoft Windows.

The second thing to know is that a browser run in a restricted environment and as such as a very limited access to the computer and its OS.

Since you are using ASP.NET MVC, then you should create a partial view that is similar to your user control if this is what you want. Also, another thing to know is that any logic behing your control need to be converted to JavaScript or jQuery. This is what browsers understand.